# WKWebView showing White Screen. PDF not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, simulator

I reset the simulator and after that found that error code in console
[Process] 0x7fc2a38db020 - [pageProxyID=24, webPageID=25, PID=20052] WebPageProxy::didFailProvisionalLoadForFrame: frameID = 3, domain = NSURLErrorDomain, code = -1100

Added Later in Top

I made the PDF locally using data and coordinate position.
I checked the PDF path, and open PDF file by external app or finder, PDF looks fine.
Even Simulator PDF opens fine. Only have issue on iPad Devices.

```
 [webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfFileName]]];
```

Load the webView using pdfFile name ( Using WKWebView )

```
  webview.scrollView.delegate=self;
    [self.view addSubview:webview];
```

Adding webView in my main view as subview.
After searching on Google & StackOverflow, found the solution and applied

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfFileName];

    NSURL *readAccessToURL = [[url URLByDeletingLastPathComponent] URLByDeletingLastPathComponent];
     // readAccessToURL == "file:///path/to/abc/"

    [webview loadFileURL:url allowingReadAccessToURL:readAccessToURL];
```

But unfortunately it's not working as well.
But in Simulator iPad Device working fine. Only issue in Real Device.
I'm adding a short video google drive link to show the issue.
Video URL = [https://drive.google.com/file/d/11jIY1HNPpILsC4XhELaaHtNG0glbW7Dh/view?usp=sharing[Issue](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11jIY1HNPpILsC4XhELaaHtNG0glbW7Dh/view?usp=sharing%5BIssue) Video][1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11jIY1HNPpILsC4XhELaaHtNG0glbW7Dh/view?usp=sharing)
Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Where are you storing the PDF? If it is in the bundle you won’t be able to read it. In that case copy it to the App cache directory before attempting to read.

Comment: The PDF file generate and stores into Device Storage. In this pdfFileName- > string variable PDF path is stored. And can be open in Go > Enter Path > Can View the PDF in mac using Simulator. Also printed in pop up the path on real device. The path is good.